# ListView: The highlight dissapears when I scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using the code below to highlight clicked item. But there are 2 problems:

- The first time I click an item, then the highlight doesn't appear. So, items are highlighted only after I click items for the second time.
- When I scroll, the highlight disappears. Instead I need that items remain highlighted until another item is clicked.

How can I resolve them?

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setSelected(true);
```

bg_key.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    android:id="@+id/myselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/activated_color" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

song_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_key">
```

Comment: the highlight disappears because the child view of list are recycled

Comment: @Redman so what can I do ? :)

Comment: i know a solution ,you can remove condition `if(convertview==null)` condition in getview() method, use this if your list has few elements, its not a recommended method

Comment: first try using view holder, if not worked then use above solution

Comment: go for recyclerview its very efficient

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep a reference to highlighted `position` in your adapter. and then

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        lvAdpapter.highlightPos = position; // declare highlightPos =-1 by default in you adapter.
```

And then inside your adapter's `getView`, do this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//existing code

songLay.setSelected(position ==highlightPos);
return songLay;
}
```

Comment: Just done, and then what Do I have to do with the reference ?

Comment: set its value in your listener and then check for value in `getview` , as i have written in above 2 snippets.

Comment: I get this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setSelected(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.xrobotx.alltest.musictest2.myAdapter.getView

Comment: you have to do it in the bottom,  on the view that you are returning. just before you return it. coul you post your getView method if that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I have just added in the question above :)

Comment: Ok I don't get any error now, but it just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Listview's `getView`() called on every scroll and for every new list item it call getView, if `listview` item currently not visible on UI then its `convertView` is equals to null:

to solve this:take an array of boolean isSelected[] with initial value false for each.

```
boolean[] isSelected = new boolean[20]; //your list view size
Arrays.fill(isSelected, false);
```

in your adapter class:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
                    string text = itemData[position]
        if (convertView == null) {
            rowLayout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtString= (TextView) rowLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            rowLayout.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            rowLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowLayout.getTag();
        }

        if(isSelected[position] == true){
                   holder.txtString.setText("Selected")
                   rowLayout.setBackGround(selected)
        }else{
             holder.txtString.setText("Not Selected")
             rowLayout.setBackGround(notSelected)
        }




    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtString;
        //your listview contents
    }
```

for your listview `oItemClick` use:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      isSelected[position] = true  // on selection

                      RelativeLayout rowLayout = (RelativeLayout) view;
                      rowLayout.setBackGround(Selected);

                    }
            });
```

Comment: What I have to put in "your listview contents" ?

Comment: it is your textview and imageview which is in the layout...also u need to initialize them in `convertView == null` condition